# Issue with included JavaScript when running Testacular unit test on Angular.js directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I'm trying to write a unit test for a directive that I use to insert a Leaflet.js map.

This tag

```
<div ng-controller="WorldMapCtrl">
    <sap id="map"></sap>
</div>
```

Is used with this controller

```
function WorldMapCtrl($scope) {}
```

And the following directive

```
angular.module('MyApp').
    directive('sap', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var map = L.map(attrs.id, {
                center: [40, -86],
                zoom: 2
            });
            //create a CloudMade tile layer and add it to the map
         L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/57cbb6ca8cac418dbb1a402586df4528/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                maxZoom: 4, minZoom: 2
            }).addTo(map);
        }
    };
});
```

This correctly inserts the map into the page. When I run the following unit test, it crashes out with

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_leaflet' of null

```
describe('directives', function() {
    beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

    // Testing Leaflet map directive
    describe('Testing Leaflet map directive', function() {
        it('should create the leaflet dir for proper injection into the page', function() {
            inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
                var element = $compile('<sap id="map"></sap>')($rootScope);
                expect(element.className).toBe('leaflet-container leaflet-fade-anim');
            })
        });
    });
});
```

From what I can tell from some Googling, the error seems to be fairly common. Perhaps not putting the tag in properly (With an id="map") or something similar can cause the problem. However, I'm not seeing what I can change with the test for this directive. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

I've also included the necessary JS files in testacular.conf.js in the same order that they're included in index.html. So, it's not an issue of the files not being there (I assume at least).

One result from Googling (sadly, it doesn't help): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/leaflet-js/2QH7aw8uUZQ/cWD3sxu8nXsJ

Comment: Just a guess, but in your test, after the call to `$compile` and before your `expect` line, try adding `$rootScope.$digest()` just in case its an issue with view not being updated.

Comment: Sadly that didn't help. Thank you though for trying.